# Core Data - update entity in background thread automatically changes NSManagedObject in Main Thread without merging- why?

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa, core-data, merge

i´m currently learning Core Data. Core Data is great but i can not explain the behaviour with a second managed object context in a background thread.

I have an entity called TestEntity with 2 attributes (testId and testDescription)
On the main thread i fetch the entity with the testId = 1 and store this managed object into an instance variable.

```
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                          entityForName:@"TestEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

NSNumber *testId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"testId == %@", testId];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *array = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

t1 = [[array objectAtIndex:0] retain];

TestThread *tt = [TestThread new];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
[queue addOperation:tt];

[queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
NSLog(@"%@", [t1 valueForKey:@"testDescription"]);
```

Then is start a NSOperation with a NSOperationQueue called TestThread.
In the main method of this TestThread i create a second managed object context, fetch the same entity (testId = 1) like the main thread, change the testDescription property and save the new context without any errors.

```
    tgAppDelegate *delegate = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

self.context = [[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] autorelease];
[context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator];


NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                          entityForName:@"TestEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

// Set example predicate and sort orderings...
NSNumber *testId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"testId == %@", testId];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
TestEntity *t1 = [array objectAtIndex:0];

t1.testDescription = @"abc";
[context save:&error];
if (error) {
    // do something
}
```

The behaviour i can not explain my self is, that the NSLog output after

```
[queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
```

has the same string value which updated in my background thread.

abc

My understanding of Core Data and Multithreading is that i have to do an explicit merge between contextes.
In my test app there is no merge.

Can anyone explain why this happenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a fetch request will return objects as faults so their content is not actually loaded until you access it (you can learn more about faulting under [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html)).

To see your expected behavior, try logging the original value of t1.testDescription before you start the second thread.

You can also set

```
self.context.returnObjectsAsFaults = NO;
```

but this might have a negative impact on the memory footprint of your app.

Comment: Thanks, your link helped me to understand this